# Google Places API not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a piece of code which was working great yesterday evening with places library to handle google maps autocomplete but this morning, I am totally unable to make it work.

I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
```

The line generating the error

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#searchBox")[0], {
    types: ['(regions)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "fr"}
});
```

Libraries are loaded before the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0t5XuHRGcvsOoWNS3QJGJyxgkdoC_V5E&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
```

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ImmoGéo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carrois+Gothic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="share" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Partager</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" id="share-url" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id='panel'>
        <div id="title">RECHERCHE</div>
        <div id="content">
             <div id="search" class="input-group">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Recherche"/><span style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#share" class="input-group-addon"><img src="img/share.png" height="20px"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <a class="btn btn-info" >ACHETER</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info" >LOUER</a>
            </div>
            <div id="criteria">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id='map-canvas'></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0t5XuHRGcvsOoWNS3QJGJyxgkdoC_V5E&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function togglePanel()
    {
        if($("#panel").css("right") == "-400px"){
            $("#panel").animate({"right": "0px"}, 800, 'easeInOutQuart', function(){
                $("#searchBox").focus();
            });
        }
        else {
            $(".pac-container").hide();
            $("#panel").animate({"right": "-400px"}, 800, 'easeInOutQuart');
        }


    }

    function init()
    {
        //set title style
        $("#title").css("width", 3*(($(window).width())/100)); //width button 3%
        $("#title").css("left", "-"+3*(($(window).width())/100)+"px"); //left -3%

        $("#title").click(function(){
           togglePanel();
        });

        //add listeners on #actions

        //LOCATING USER
        userPosition = new Object();
        userPosition.latitude = 48.85;
        userPosition.longitude = 2.4;

        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                function (pos){
                    if(userPosition.latitude != pos.coords.latitude || userPosition.longitude != pos.coords.longitude)
                    {
                        userPosition.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                        userPosition.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
                        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(userPosition.latitude, userPosition.longitude);
                        map.panTo(pos);
                    }
                },
                null,
                {enableHighAccuracy:true}
            );            
        }
        else
            alert("Votre navigateur ne prend pas en compte la géolocalisation HTML5");

        //MAP OPTIONS
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),{
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(userPosition.latitude, userPosition.longitude),
            streetViewControl: false,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeControl: true
        });

        //SEARCHBOX
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#searchBox")[0], {
            types: ['(regions)'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: "fr"}
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = searchBox.getPlace();
            if(typeof searchMarker !== 'undefined')
                searchMarker.setMap(null);

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(13);  // Why 13? Because it looks good.
            }
            //create markers for each results
            searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).load(init());

</script>
```

Is there any chance the google disabled the API for my referer ?
Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting sensor=false , like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0t5XuHRGcvsOoWNS3QJGJyxgkdoC_V5E&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

I had a similar issue, where autocomplete stopped working this morning, with no changes. I tracked it down to this change, and it works again.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading Google API two times:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0t5XuHRGcvsOoWNS3QJGJyxgkdoC_V5E&libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
```

You have to merge those two link into one like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0t5XuHRGcvsOoWNS3QJGJyxgkdoC_V5E&libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
```

Besides that some of other links have missing `http:` at the beginning. Check your console log for error messages.

Comment: Thought libraries=places would load only the places methods. My bad.
Well done tho, but why did it stop working suddenly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use it without sensor parameter

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deverrorcodes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA0t5XuHRGcvsOoWNS3QJGJyxgkdoC_V5E&libraries=places"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution somewhere else that advises separating the queries in the request when loading google places library see sample below:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=******************&libraries=places";
              "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=******************&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

this worked for me using Cordova;

link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-places-results-not-showing-on-mobile-solved/107210